# Estimating ETH transfer and ERC20 transfer gas always returns same value

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to estimate erc20 transfer fee and eth transfer fee. However, the gasestimate always return the same value for both ethTransferGasEstimate and erc20TransferGasEstimate

- ethTransferGasEstimate always = 21000
- erc20TransferGasEstimate always = 68408

```
     [ ethTransferGasEstimate, erc20TransferGasEstimate, feeHistory, feeHistoryPendingBlock ] = await Promise.all([
                await web3.eth.estimateGas(ethTransferCallData),
                await usdc_contract.estimateGas.transfer(TO_ADDRESS_ETH_MAINNET, 100,{
                    from: FROM_ADDRESS_ETH_MAINNET
                }),
                await web3.eth.getFeeHistory(10, "latest",[10, 50, 90]),
                await web3.eth.getFeeHistory(1, "pending",[10, 50, 90])
            ])

const baseFeePerGas = parseInt(feeHistoryPendingBlock.baseFeePerGas,16)
            const rewardPerGas = feeHistory.reward.map(b => parseInt(b[1],16)).reduce((a, v) => a + v);
            const priorityFeePerGasEstimate = Math.round(rewardPerGas/feeHistory.reward.length);
            const ethTransferFee = ((baseFeePerGas+priorityFeePerGasEstimate)*ethTransferGasEstimate)/10**18
            const erc20TransferFee = ((baseFeePerGas+priorityFeePerGasEstimate)*erc20TransferGasEstimate.toNumber())/10**18
            
            console.log("--------Ethers.js----------")
            console.log("gas estimate eth transfer",ethTransferGasEstimate.toString())
            console.log("total fee", ethTransferFee)
            console.log("gas estimate usdc_contract transfer", erc20TransferGasEstimate.toString())
            console.log("total fee", erc20TransferFee)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each low-level operation (read from memory, write to storage, ...) of the contract has a predetermined price in gas units. When the estimator adds up all of these operations, you get the amount of gas units in your `ethTransferGasEstimate` and `erc20TransferGasEstimate` variables.

*Note: Some contract logic and the resulting final list of operations might depend on data that is not known before executing the transaction, that's why it's just an estimation.*

Gas units are then automatically bought for ETH - this is the transaction fee. Their price is market driven, you can see the current prices for example at https://etherscan.io/gastracker or you can get your node provider's estimation of current market price with [provider.getGasPrice()](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getGasPrice).

Currently, the market gas price is around 7 Gwei (= 7 million wei) per each gas unit. So with this price, the ETH transfer would cost you 21,000 gas units == 147,000,000,000 wei == 0.000000147 ETH. And the ERC20 transfer would currently cost you 68,408 gas units == 478,856,000,000 wei == 0.000000478856 ETH.